# Java DataInputStream readAllBytes empty?

Tags: java, tcp, tcpclient

I have a TCP Client and Server in Java and want to send a byte array from the Client to the Server. Im sending the bytes using this method:

```java
    public void writeBytes(byte[] message, Socket socket) throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.write(message);
        out.flush();
    }
```

But I can't receive them with the `readAllBytes` method from `DataInputStream` / `InputStream`

```java
    public void readMsg(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(in.readAllBytes()); //would be empty
    }
```

Theoretically, I could send the size of the byte array + the byte array itself and read them with the `readFully(size)` method. That would work. But I want to understand why it doesn't work with the `readAllBytes` method.

Comment: Are you sure that code compiles? Which version of Java are you using, because I can't find the method readAllBytes for DataInputStream

Comment: The code should compile properly. But it seems that it may be stuck at `System.out.println(in.readAllBytes());`. Im using Java 9 and `readAllBytes` should be in `InputStream.java`

Comment: Ok, that is clearer. readAllBytes is new in Java 9. The documentation says it will read until an end of stream is detected. That means until the stream is closed on the sending side.

Comment: It might be better to use a BufferedInputStream

Comment: If you're going to be keeping the connections open for a bit, you might want to not close the stream each time.